# Wordpress Redirect to service page url

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I use wordpress for my website. I installed plugin to add services. I want when click on button 'view more' to opan new page with content of this service. Everything with create and update the service is ok, but when i try to preview or opan the service page i have error 404, becouse in url have website.com/services/first-service .. i do not understand why ...
and the second question is how to construct url link to the service page ? 
here is my code for show the service - title and the_excerpt:

```
    $query = new WP_Query( array(
     'post_type' => 'services',
     'orderby' => 'date',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'posts_per_page' => 4
  ) );

  if( $query->have_posts() ) {
      while( $query->have_posts() ) {
          $query->the_post();
  ?>
        <div class="jobs-table col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ">
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10">
          <h4 class="title-jobs-table"><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
          <h5 class="job-table-sub" style="color: rgb(68, 63, 63);"><?php  
          the_excerpt();?></h5>
          <?php if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
              $image_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(),'full' );
               echo '<img src="' . $image_src[0]  . '" width="200px" height="200px"  />';
          } ?>
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2">
            <a class="btn-table-job"> <span>виж повече</span> </a>
          </div>
        </div>

      <?php

      }
  }
```

?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the url in your loop. Try it like this:

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"class="btn-table-job"> <span>виж повече</span> </a>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_permalink

for custom post types (like services) it´s normal that you have the post type slug in your url.
Sometimes you need to regenerate the permalink structure after adding a new custom post type.

Got to Settings -> permalinks -> and click save.